# Best VPN package for a group of 8 people doing majority online gaming

Tags: software-recommendation, vpn

I'd like to host a private VPN for online gaming purpose? What will be the best suitable solution? I've heard of pptpd and openvpn, also know that windows could not connect to openvpn using its built in VPN client despite of its security benefits.

My another concern is in terms of speed, which package would transmit data faster(even a little faster)?

Thanks for kindly help.

Comment: This was closed as abandoned. Since it has [an upvoted answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/236829/22949) (mine), it really shouldn't be considered abandoned. I recommend reopening this.

Comment: @EliahKagan, this question seems off-topic to me. Both the question and answer seem to be centred around the use of Windows instead of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

If the machines on the VPN are all running Windows and the purpose of the VPN is to facilitate Windows gaming, and you have a powerful computer running Windows that you use for gaming, then you might just want to use *that* as your VPN server. Regardless of what VPN solution you choose, there's no fundamental reason why the server must be separate from the machines using the VPN.

Whether you host the VPN with Windows, Ubuntu, or some other OS, it seems from your question that you're most interested in knowing about the advantages of various VPN's from the perspective of Windows usability and performance. Therefore, you might get better answers if you were to ask a reformulated version of your question somewhere Windows is supported, such as [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Since you're using Windows, presumably you're willing to use proprietary software. (Many games have proprietary engines, too.) So you might consider using [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/) (see also [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamachi_%28software%29)). It's proprietary but not payware unless you use some of the more advanced features. It provides VPN *without the need for a VPN server*. Hamachi supports Windows and Mac OS X and has a beta client for GNU/Linux (including Ubuntu). This may work well even if the VPN must be accessed robustly by Ubuntu (for example, if you run dedicated game servers on an Ubuntu machine). If the VPN need only be accessed casually by Ubuntu, then this will almost certainly work well.